# Showing the ActionBar in IMMERSIVE_STICKY mode

Tags: android

I've successfully enabled immersive sticky mode, but the action bar no longer appears.

I added this to my ActionBarActivity to get the system/navbar to go away and reappear on swipe from the side:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

    }
}
```

And reading the docs indicated that I should add this code in the onCreate method.  What I find is the onSystemUiVisibilityChange() routine is just not called when the UI becomes visible again.  I do see it called when the app is started up in fullscreen mode, so it does hide() the actionBar.  But, show() never gets called.

```
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
                (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                        // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
                        // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
                        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                            // The system bars are visible.
                            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                            actionBar.show();
                        } else {
                            // The system bars are NOT visible.
                            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                            actionBar.hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

So, how can I get a callback when the system UI reappears?

I'm on NVIDIA SHIELD Tablet Android 5

Comment: This bug appears relevant, but completely non-helpful.  What is "obsolete" about this issue?  Why can this be closed?  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66702

Comment: Full code is here if it helps: https://github.com/rogerallen/GridStrument/blob/af50bbc840438f885e489e09fd05c44432a4b130/app/src/main/java/com/gmail/rallen/gridstrument/MainActivity.java#L76

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with your use of SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY.  If you look at the developer docs for immersive mode, it states:

> Note that the "sticky" version of the flag doesn't trigger any
>   listeners,  as system bars temporarily shown in this mode are in a
>   transient state

Full reference can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html